# Symfony3 empty session id

Tags: symfony, session, sessionid, symfony-3.3

I am getting a session id in twig

```
{{app.session.getid()}}
```

every time I open the site for the first time in a new window I get an empty session id.

After that, if I refresh the page then it gives the correct session id.

Anyone having any idea why this is happening?

I am using symfony 3.3.9.

Comment: Why do you need the session id?

Comment: need to set session id in third party script